# Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight and XAML ListView substitute

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight application. Its very similar to a e-commerce app. I need something similar to a ListView. But that is not supported in Silverlight apps due to the missing Windows.UI.Xaml in them. So any suggestions for alternatives and corresponding template???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ListBox or LongListSelector.

Comment: @igrali yes i tried those. But each item needs to have a pic, three text boxes to display name, quantity and price. All the data being dynamically fetched by a server. Is that possible??

Comment: Of course. That's what those controls are for! You define ItemTemplate with a picture and TextBoxes/TextBlocks just as you would with the ListView, bind to data and that's it!